# Apache Cordova app deployment on Windows Phone emulator

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, visual-studio-cordova

Basically, I have the Ultimate version of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, Tools for Apache Cordova for VS2013 CTP 3.1 and WP 8.1 Update 1 SDK and Emulators installed. I created a blank Apache Cordova app and immediately tried to run it on different platforms. I tried Ripple for Android/iOS and Android Simulator, and they all worked fine but Windows Phone emulators, however, did not. When trying to run a, for example, Emulator WVGA 8.1 4 inch 512 MB image, Visual Studio goes into "Im busy and waiting for an internal operation to complete" mode and stops responding, after getting it to wake up, it shows following deployment errors:

```
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device':  DeviceNotFoundException - Exception of type  'Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException' was thrown.  

Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Preparing for start': DeviceNotFoundException - Exception of type 'Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException' was thrown. 

BootstrapAsync returned false.
```

I have a SLAT capable machine and Hyper-V is running, I can easily start up and run a Windows Phone 8.1 VM, I also changed the app windows target version to 8.1 but to no avail. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators was necessary instead of Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 Emulators

Comment: Does your Win Phone 8.1 emulator work for a native Windows Phone 8.1 app built without Cordova tools?

Comment: Yeah, it did, but I got the WP 8.1 Emulator images (not Update 1), which worked just fine with Cordova apps.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem and to solve it, I just restarted IPoverUSBsvc from going to the services. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, I try to reset Windows10 and reset VS2015.2 and could't solute this problem. I study it for many days, finally, i successed;

ths solution is setup Windows8 SDK when you setup Visual Studio 2015 update2, 
although I don't understand why should I setup WP8 SDK, it windows10 mobile, not WP8, But that's work。 Now I can deployment my cordova app on Windows10 mobile.